# sandbox paypal La transaction a expire

Tags: paypal-sandbox

*Here's the correct translation for this question, which was originally asked in french. Note that I have taken liberty to translate the comments in the code.*

---

My procedure worked correctly during tests in my sandbox. When I put it into operational mode, it still worked correctly. Then I added a check in my code to prevent access to the sandbox version by copy/pasting the URL. Now my website works correctly in operational mode, but my sandbox vresion doesn't work anymore.

[Link to operational mode](http://www.tousassure.fr/nvp.php?devis=1322701).

[Link to sandbox mode](http://www.tousassure.fr/nvp.php?devis=1312201).

The procedure:

```
//
//  VENDOR PARAMETERS FOR SANDBOX VERSION
//
if ($proctest == "1")                           
{   
    $url_nvp = 'https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp';     // Sandbox version 
    $version = 64.0;                                        // Version 
    $iduser  = 'f-facilitator_api1.x.fr';       // User
    $passwrd = '0123456789';                                // Password
                                                            // Signature 
    $signature = 'AFcWxV21C7fd0v3bYYYRCpSSRl31ALWKEzeddmFHrClYoc6tJpZiawjH';    
}
//
//  VENDOR PARAMETERS FOR OPERATIONAL VERSION
//
else                                    
{
    $url_nvp = 'https://api-3t.paypal.com/nvp';             // Operational website 
    $version = 64.0;                                        // Version 
    $iduser  = 'f_api1.x.fr';                   // User 
    $passwrd = '0123456789';                            // Password 
                                                            // Signature 
    $signature = 'Apekq0Tf.isqMqkIsEX7RsjIFTVCA8EehX5M263oELbE40NBWWYxhtW1';    
}
// 
//  BUILDING THE STRING
//
$api_paypal= $url_nvp.'?VERSION='   .$version           // Builds the URL
                     .'&USER='      .$iduser
                     .'&PWD='       .$passwrd
                     .'&SIGNATURE=' .$signature;    
return $api_paypal;                                     // Returns the string
  }
```

Then:

```
    //
    //  TEST ENVIRONMENT FOR NVP'S API
    //
    if ($proctest == "1")                                       
    {   
        header("Location: https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webscr&cmd=_express-checkout&token=".$liste_param_paypal['TOKEN']);
    }
    //
    //  OPERATIONAL ENVIRONMENT FOR NVP'S API
    //
    else                            
    {
        header("Location: https://www.paypal.com/webscr&cmd=_express-checkout&token=".$liste_param_paypal['TOKEN']);
    }
```

I can't find what prevents the sandbox version from running correctly.